# How to find tables with self referencing Foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2016, stored-procedures, foreign-key

Hi is there any query to get all self referencing foreign keys .  I need to get the all tables and the foreign keys in a database with sled referring and drop and create it .Any idea how to do it .?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DMVs - more specifically [sys.foreign_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```sql
SELECT
    fk.object_id AS FkId
    , fk.name AS FkName
    , fk.parent_object_id AS TableId
    , OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) AS TableName
FROM
    sys.foreign_keys AS fk
WHERE
    fk.referenced_object_id = fk.parent_object_id
```